# Node.Js async request inside a Array.forEach not completing before wiriting a json file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, request, cheerio

I'm making a web scraper Node.js app that harvests job description text from various urls.. I currently have an **array of job objects named jobObj** and **the code cycles through each url**, makes a **request for html**, **loads using cheerio module** then finally makes a new object with jobName and jobDesc keys and pushes it onto a new array of objects that is then written as a json file....

All this currently works however the **completeness of the written json file is very random** and usually only contains one complete job account.  I thought this may be due to the forEach loop completing much quicker than the asynchronous Request function thus resulting in execution of the fs.writefile before request callback is completed.  I've added a counter to monitor at what stage the requests are at and only write the json file once counter===jobObj.length but still the json file is not fully complete.

I'm new to node.js if someone could please point out my error it would be greatly appreciated!

```
var jobObj = [
{
id:1, 
url:"https://www.indeed.co.uk/cmp/Daffodil-IT/jobs/Lead-Junior-Website-Developer-59ea7d446bdf1253?q=Junior+Web+Developer&vjs=3",
}, 
{
id:2, 
url:"https://www.indeed.co.uk/cmp/Crush-Design/jobs/Middleweight-Web-Developer-541331b7885c03cf?q=Web+Developer&vjs=3",
},
{
id:3,
url:"https://www.indeed.co.uk/cmp/Monigold-Solutions/jobs/Graduate-Web-Software-Engineer-a5787dc322c0ca36?q=Web+Developer&vjs=3",
},
{
id:4,
url:"https://www.indeed.co.uk/cmp/ZOO-DIGITAL-GROUP-PLC/jobs/Web-Developer-5cdde1c3b0b7b8d0?q=Web+Developer&vjs=3",
},
{
id:5,
url:"https://www.indeed.co.uk/viewjob?jk=9cc3d8c637c41067&q=Web+Developer&l=Sheffield&tk=1cf5di52e9u0ocam&from=web&vjs=3",
}
];


app.get('/myform', function(req, res){

res.send("<h1>" + `scanning ${jobObj.length} urls for job description text` + "</h1>");
//make assign input form data to node "url" variable

//Compnonents for a request counter
var jobs = new Array;
function scrapeFinished(){console.log("all websites scraped!");};
var itemsProcessed = 0;   

jobObj.forEach(function(item){

    request(item.url, function(err, res, html){

        if(!err){

            var $ = cheerio.load(html);
            var newJob = new Object;
            $('#job_summary').each(function(){
                var data = $(this);
                var textout = data.text();
                newJob.jobDesc = textout;    
            });

            $('.jobtitle').each(function(){
                var data = $(this);
                var jobtitle = data.text();
                newJob.jobName = jobtitle;
            });

            jobs.push(newJob);
            itemsProcessed++;
            console.log(item.url + " scraped");  

            if(itemsProcessed === jobObj.length){
            scrapeFinished();

            fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(jobs, null, "\t"), function(err){ 
            if(!err){console.log("output.json file written")}
            })
            }
        }      
    })           
})


})
```

And finally this is what I get on `fs.writefile`

```
[
{},
{
    "jobDesc": "We are a successful design and digital agency that works with some great clients on a wide range of digital projects.We simply need more developers to join our great team to deliver even more great work.The projects we work on are all php based, typically built using WordPress, Laravel or flat html.We are seen as a premium agency because of the quality and complexity of the work we do.That means you will have to do more that just manipulate a theme - you will have to code. But you will be given the space, time and support to do so.We want you to be proud of the work you do, because the reputation of the agency need you to be.Key skills we will want you to bringCSS (CSS3) & HTMLAt least some knowledge of MySQL and JavaScript.At least some knowledge PHP (seniors will be tested)PhotoshopWhat you will want that we can giveA good place to work with a friendly teamA chance to develop your coding craftA decent range of projects to challenge yourselfA senior developer on hand to coach and adviseA successful company with an optimistic outlook, growth plans and a secure futureExactly how much experience you have can vary, but you must have some. And the more experience you have, the more we will pay you.We are based in offices we own in the centre of Chesterfield will two staff that do the short commute from Sheffield.If you think this job sounds interesting, we would love to hear from you, please apply!(though not agencies please)Job Type: Full-timeSalary: £22,000.00 to £30,000.00 /yearExperience:development: 2 years",
    "jobName": "Middleweight web developer"
},
{},
{},
{}
]
```

Answer (score -1):

*forEach* run in *synchronous* fashion so no matter how much time it will get to scrap the webpage, it won't run for the next array item. What can cause trouble here is your code maybe pushing an object in the array before scrapping the webpage. This is why you are getting an empty object. What you do is to push object after your program finishes visiting the URL.
Do something like this

```
 jobObj.forEach(function (item) {

    var newJob = new Object;
    request(item.url, function (err, res, html) {
        // Scrap URL and save values in newJob 
    });
            jobs.push(newJob);
});
```

if your code still pushes an empty object before completing the request then consider using [Async](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async) module.

Comment: moving the push() didn't solve but did result in a grand total of 3 job accounts completing!  current pb!  Will have a go with the ASYNC module, cheers!

Comment: although would the asynchronous request just skip to the push() function whilst waiting for the callback?

Comment: Nah. I don't think so. What is your new output after moving the push() outside the request?